# How to learn Skylab Twin Shot with my custom player?

Tags: captain-tsubasa-rise-new-champions

As fas as I understood, it's possible to unlock *Skylab Twin Shot* during Argentina match befriending both Tachibana twins to A and Jito to S.

But how can I learn that technique for my custom player? I know it's possible, since I saw that in several YT videos.

And as a side note, I'm wondering if my custom player always replaces Jito in the combination, or is it possible to "be" one of Tachibana twins and actually score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to learn that technique, but unfortunately you can only replace Jito in the combination (as confirmed by the [wiki](https://captaintsubasa.fandom.com/wiki/Skylab_Twin_Shot)), meaning that your custom player cannot score nor even get an assist. Bummer.

However, to unlock *Skylab Twin Shot* from Tachibanas you need to:

1. Raise Jito and both Tachibana twins friendship to A
2. Get an extra event when they ask you to help them with a new technique. This must be done **before** Argentina match, since you unlock the shot during half time. (I don't know if you have to let Diaz score with his overhead super shot, but I did, it was suggested online).

It's not important to use *Skylab Twin Shot* during the match, I couldn't for whatever reason.

After that match, I raised Tachibana twins to S and got another extra event where Tachibanas and Jito asked me to try the newly acquired shot, and they taught the technique to my custom player.

---

Unfortunately, the ultimate Twin Shot used to be an SSS shot, but it was heavily nerfed (after everybody abused it online, I guess) leaving it with [A power - B speed]. Even worse than [Skylab Triangle](https://captaintsubasa.fandom.com/wiki/Skylab_Triangle). Really cool to use, but definitely NOT worth it.